# Proving a recursion is less than two

Tags: recursion

The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined by $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and
$a_n = a_{n - 1}^2 + a_{n - 1}$ for $n \ge 2.$

Prove that
$\frac{1}{a_1 + 1} + \frac{1}{a_2 + 1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n + 1} < 2$ for all $n \ge 1.$

So far, I have manipulated the given recursion into $a_n = a_{n - 1} (a_{n - 1} + 1)$. But now I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: $a_{k+1} = a_k(a_k+1) \implies \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} = \frac{1}{a_k(a_k+1)}
= \frac{1}{a_k} - \frac{1}{a_k+1}  \iff
\frac{1}{a_k+1} = \frac{1}{a_k} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}}
$

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all we have by @hdighfan solution: $$\frac{1}{a_n~+1}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$$ By telescopic summing we have
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k~+1}=\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}<2,$$
as $a_1=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish i could upvote you and @hdighfan

Comment: @fds-mqdwqmqkdwl you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We claim a stronger result; namely that $\frac{1}{a_1+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}+1} + \frac{1}{a_n}<2$, for all $n$. This obviously holds for small $n$; you can check this yourself.

Observe that
$$\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{(a_{n+1}+1)a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_n+1} + \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}.$$

The claim follows by induction.